# Qt OpenGL texture won't appear

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using Qt to create a simple sprite editor with OpenGL, but the image just doesn't show up, it's just a white quad on the screen.

I have checked my code, and I think everything is right. The quad is of the same size of the image and the texture id is not 0.

Here's my code:

Initialization:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, win_width, win_height, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Texture loading:

```
QImage b = QImage(filename);
m_texture = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(b);

glGenTextures(1, &m_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
             m_texture.width(),
             m_texture.height(),
             0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             m_texture.bits());
```

Render:

```
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_id);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2i(0, 0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2i(m_texture.width(), 0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2i(m_texture.width(), m_texture.height());

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2i(0, m_texture.height());

glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

This is what I'm getting so far:
[image: White Quad]

Comment: what does it say when you print the opengl version? i.e. glGetString(GL_VERSION) and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)

Comment: @faraza
`Version: 2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2900`
`Shading Language Version: 1.20  - Intel Build 8.15.10.2900`

Comment: Yeah, the problem might be that you're using the older version of opengl. I'm guessing that you're on Mac? Unless you explicitly set the OpenGL version to 3+, you'll default to 2.1

Comment: I'm using PC. Windows.
My "graphics card" only supports OpenGL 2.1 and some features of 3.2.
It's weird because it only works outside of Qt, I have a lot of apps using modern OpenGL.
EDIT: If I manually set the OpenGL version, I get:
`Version: (null)
Shading Language Version: (null)`

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the OpenGL version to 3.2.

```
QGLFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(3, 2);
glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
```

After you do that, print your OpenGL version with glGetString().

If you're still getting 2.1, you didn't set it in the correct OpenGL context. I'm not sure exactly how you're making your OpenGL calls, but I was using QT Creator Designer, and was embedding a QGLWidget within the main window. So I was successfully able to set the OpenGL version by setting it within the MainWindow constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QGLFormat glFormat;
    glFormat.setVersion(3, 2);
    glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
    QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```